# angular doesn't render $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to display some variable of my controller, but the output is just `{{UserCtrl.user}}` instead of the content of `UserCtrl.user`.

I got the following file structure:

- `index.html`
- `scripts/app.js`

This is the code of `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="birdsnest">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Birdsnest</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="UserController as UserCtrl">
        {{UserCtrl.user}}
    </div>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`scripts/app.js`:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('birdsnest', []);

  app.controller('UserController', ['scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'Michael';
  }]);
})();
```

Comment: I can't see the `ng-app`. Where  you define the app?

Comment: Yes, it's in the html tag: `<html lang="en" ng-app="birdsnest">`

Comment: Sorry. missed that.
Do you see any errors on console?

Comment: You need to put the JS includes on top of everything, not below. (in the `<head>` section)

Comment: Done, but same result as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
app.controller('UserController', ['scope', function($scope) {
```

To:

```
 app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

Edit:
If you're using `controllerAs` then I think you should rewrite your code:

```
app.controller('UserController', function() {
  this.user = 'Michael';
});
```

Comment: When I do this I don't get any output.

Comment: Oh I just noticed that if I change it to this it works: `<div ng-controller="UserController">
        {{user}}
    </div>` Can someone explain me why?

Comment: @MichaelPittino - I have updated my answer, please check if it helps

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the `ControllerAs` syntax in your HTML, the values that end up getting bound to the controller instance is actually on your `this` object.

What this means is that your code that attaches `user` to the `scope` object is incorrect; instead you should do the following:

```
app.controller("UserController", function() {
  this.user = "Michael";
});
```